# web.config url rewrite conditions

Tags: asp.net, url, web-config, url-rewriting, conditional-statements

I have a problem aplaying a condition to my Url - Rewriting. It looks like that right now:

```
 <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Test/chid-cid/tabid-tid to Test.aspx?chid=cid und tabid=tid">
      <match url="^([^/]+)-([^/]+)/([^/]+)-([^/]+)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?chid={R:2}&amp;tabid={R:4}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Test to Test.aspx">
      <match url="^default"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

so as the name tells it converts default/chname-cid/tab-name-tid to default.aspx?chid=cid&tabid=tid

this works fine, but when i want to swtich language the URL is wrong. It should got to default.aspx?_EVENT...
but it goes to default/chname-cid/default.aspx?_EVENT ... 
now i tried to use a condition to search the PATH_INFO if it contains "_EVENT" and if thats the case dont use the rewrite rule. Like that:

```
<conditions>
   <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^_EVENT" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

but it didnt work... 
can anybody help me how the condtion should look like in that case

Thank you for your help!